# SQL Query criteria to get data by date

Tags: mysql

I've a doubt on SQL Query.

Actually my problem is I have to retrieve data using date (Criteria).

For Example, lets assume a table named "Plans".  It have columns PLANID and EXPIRY_TIME(plan expiry time in milliseconds).

Both columns are ***BIGINT*** datatype.

I have to retrieve all rows, who all are having plan expiry date as today.

Like, today date is 17. Then result must have expiry date as 17 from any month and any year.

For that, I had surfed. I found a way to convert milliseconds to  date. But it was working on "date" datatype only where I have type as "BIGINT".

That Function is *FROM_UNIXTIME()*;

Is there any way to do it?

Advance thanks for the help!

Comment: How are the Workbench and mysqldump tags relevant exactly? Do you want to run a partial backup or something?

Comment: No, I'm just a learner now. I don't know about that. I think its a basic query. So, added that. sorry. Removed that tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT `plan`.`PLANID`,
`plan`.`EXPIRY_TIME`,
FROM_UNIXTIME(`plan`.`EXPIRY_TIME`/1000, '%d-%m-%Y') as plan_expiry
FROM `Test`.`plan`;
```

The important point is dividing by 1000 to get seconds like stated here:

[Convert BigInt timestamp to a real Date with row aggregation and operations in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585245/convert-bigint-timestamp-to-a-real-date-with-row-aggregation-and-operations-in-m)

Result:

```
PLANID      EXPIRY_TIME       plan_expiry
1           1458211499228     17-03-2016
```

Regards