# mysql convert bigint to datetime

Tags: mysql, bigint

The `CreateDateTime` column in a table is in the format bigint(20). For example it looks like: 131037078373067074. I didn't create this table, it is passed on to me.

Using the example here [Convert BigInt timestamp to a real Date with row aggregation and operations in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585245/convert-bigint-timestamp-to-a-real-date-with-row-aggregation-and-operations-in-m), I have tried dividing CreateDateTime by `POW(10,8)` or `POW(10,9)` .

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(CreateDateTime/POW(10,8)) AS due_date 
FROM  images;
```

results look like '2011-07-11 02:53:03.730671'.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(CreateDateTime/POW(10,9)) AS due_date 
FROM  images;
```

results look like '1974-02-25 09:11:18.373067'.

I am expecting a date in 2016. However dividing `CreateDateTime` by `POW(10,7)` gives null.

What should I do?

Comment: Where did that value (`131004014587920371`) came from? What is it represents?

Comment: Is your system clock right?  I get 2011 as well, assuming this is a microsecond timestamp.  Nothing else seems to make sense, unless the code's epoch is off (say, the author's birthdate, because he's a jerk programmer).

Comment: @JohnGreen I don't have system time available. Can you explain why in the link I mentioned, time is divided by POW(10,3), while I need to use POW(10,8)? I don't know the theory behind it, I am just trying different number of power.

Comment: @Echo `FROM_UNIXTIME` expects the number to be seconds since the beginning of 1970. If the number is actually milliseconds, you divide by 1000 to convert milliseconds to seconds. If it's microseconds you divide by 1,000,000. You have to divide by whatever fraction of a second the number actually represents.

Comment: @Barmar, if it is microsecond, I should divide by POW(10,6) right? How would I know what to divide, or I just try different number, see what sticks?

Comment: You have to know what the number represents. Whoever provided the data should be able to tell you.

Comment: Also, if it uses a different base time than Jan 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT, you'll need to add or subtract the difference.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! How do I find the base time? Whoever provide the data should provide to me?

Comment: Yes. A number is meaningless unless someone tells you how to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am expecting a date in 2016.

Dividing by 89000000 gives a date in 2016

(To discover that I converted a date in the middle of 2016 to seconds since unix epoch and divided your number by that).

> What should I do?

If you have some way to get the real datetime (like from an existing and known working user interface) you can probably reverse engineer the formula.  Take several samples and keep track of the number in CreateDateTime and the correct date time.  The number may represent microseconds or nanoseconds since a different epoch.  Unix uses 1970-01-01 UTC, Excel uses Jan 0, 1900 (no, not Jan 1 but Jan 1 - 24 hours), NTP uses Jan 1 1900, IBM BIOS (and ZIP) uses Jan 1, 1980.
The number of "fractional seconds" in one second may be a multiple of 60 instead of 10.

Use the data you gather from the user interface to solve for

(CreateDateTime + a) / b = UnixSecondsSince1970_01_01

OR

(CreateDateTime / b) + a = UnixSecondsSince1970_01_01

where "a" is the offset needed to adjust for non-unix epoch and "b" is the number of units needed to add up to one second in the "CreateDateTime" representation.

Others epoch choices referenced here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing

( 131037078373067074 / 10000000000  + ( 24 * 60 * 60 * 17000 ) )

Also gives a date in 2016