# how to convert datetime into bigint in mysql?

Tags: mysql

The current datetime value shall be stored in a column with the datatype `bigint(10)`

How can i convert the current datetime into bigint in mysql?

Please suggest your solution.

Comment: What is the rule of converting a datetime to a number in your case?

Comment: rule means?. Please explain

Comment: Well, how exactly should the today's date `2017-03-10 00:00:00` be presented as a number? Eg, would it simply be `20170310000000` or what?

Comment: not like 20170310000000.When we convert datetime to bigint means it gives different numbers like 1336761000.

Comment: So, first find how you want it to be stored. If you don't know what you want to achieve, how you're going to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your interest.i want to store bigint value of current datetime. That i asked as a question.i achieved through my requirement using UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())

Comment: "bigint value of current datetime" --- this requirement makes no sense. Next time you start solving a problem make sure you completely understand what result you want to achieve.

Comment: In case you want to [convert bigint to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755309/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ... )`